# Using malloc for a dynamic array in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have this following piece of code.

I am getting segfaulted when I iterate on `*attachmentsArray` after the first iteration, even though `size==3` .
What am I doing wrong here?

```
void secondary(char** array, long size)
{

   *array = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       *array[i] = '.';
   }
}
void main()
{
    char* attachmentsArray;
    long size = 3;
    secondary(&attachmentsArry, size);
}
```

Comment: Is the name of the first parameter of `secondary()` supposed to be `attachmentsArray`?  That seems to be the name used in the function body.

Comment: What do you mean by `size==10`? Please post a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry, typo.

Comment: @MikeCAT fixed it, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the relative precedence of the `*` and `[]` operators. Your line:

```c
    *array[i] = '.';
```

is de-referencing (or trying to) the 'ith' element in an array of pointers.

What you need, to access the 'ith' element of the array *pointed-to* by `array` is this:

```c
    (*array)[i] = '.';
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Amazing!

Where can I read about the relative precedence of operators?

Comment: @willywill997 [Here!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 3):

The indexing operator (`[]`) has higher precedence than the dereferencing operator (unary `*`).  Indeed, the highest operator-precedence tier consists of all the postfix operators.  Therefore,

```
   *array[i] = '.'
```

is equivalent to

```
   *(array[i]) = '.'
```

. This is valid in that the expression `array[i]` has type `char *`, and in that sense is a valid operand for unary `*`, but for `i` other than zero, `array[i]` does not designate a valid pointer, and it is not surprising that trying to dereference it causes a segfault.

Instead, you want

```
   (*array)[i] = '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault is due to *array[i]="." because what malloc only returns a pointer to the starting address of the memory allocated you cant iterator directly by indexing..

other answers are also correct but you can also do it with incrementing the pointer to point corresponding address blocks like *array = "."; *array++;